# libraries for applying effects to video

Tags: android, opencv, video-processing

As far as I know, there are many libraries for applying effects to image frames like [opencv](http://opencv.org), [GPUImage](https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage) library and many more...

like this, are there any open source libraries for applying effects (like blur,gaussian,blend,brightness etc etc) to video in Android?